# Listening for Server Sent Events in .NET Core

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, console-application, server-sent-events

I have a .NET Core Console Application. My goal is to consume an API that ["supports streaming over the Server Sent Event / Event Stream protocol."](https://www.mbta.com/developers/v3-api/streaming)

In their site, they have an [example curl request](https://www.mbta.com/developers/v3-api/streaming) (at the very bottom).

When I run this in a terminal with a valid API Key, I get an initial response (as their site states), and then the connection appears to remain alive until a new event is published. Seems like a no brainer.

Now I would like to do this from my console app. Ideally, I want to open a connection and provide a callback, like an event handler, that will be run whenever a new event of a certain type is published. The provided callback would also capture the event.

How can I achieve this using .NET Core? What class provides the ability to do this? (open connection -> provide callback for when an event comes through) ? I have been searching but have yet to find something fit for the job.